# Formal proof of $h(x,y)=f(x)+g(y)$ has a critical point $(x_0,y_0)$ iff $x_0$ is a critical point of f and $y_0$ is a critical point of g

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

The question is basically all in the subject, so I'll just copy and paste and move on to what I've tried.

Formal proof of $h(x,y)=f(x)+g(y)$ has a critical point $(x_0,y_0)$ iff $x_0$ is a critical point of f and $y_0$ is a critical point of g

Extra: $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and the same for g

Firstly:

It's obviously true, this took me by surprise because I'd have taken this without proof, I may have even used it before and considered it too trivial to question, f's change is independent of g's because one is in x and the other y. There should be a name for how useful of a property this is.

I'm not even sure how to word it, you can think of the partials a the derivative of f along the x axis and derivative of g along the y axis, if one is turning (I sometimes call critical points turning points, it's how I was taught, is this wrong?) and the other isn't it's obviously not a critical point of the surface. It's difficult to explain, I just hope it's not so obscure someone suspects I'm bluffing, or that this is a part of that bluff and so forth, I hope no body things I have an odd numbered bluff!

I'm a little thrown off by the if and only if part. I could use the second derivative test (and use the fact that $h_xy$ and $h_yx$ are both zero) but this is actually part 2 of the question, and if that were 0 requires further investigation involving the third derivatives, if that's 0, the fourth, I've proved this by induction before but only for single variables, the question is only worth 4 marks ~ 8 minutes at most.

So yes, how would I prove this?

**additionally (this probably should have gone first)**

It does say critical, and the definition of that is "first derivatives being zero", I can show if this is true then it's a turning point? Then assume both derivatives are zero, and, well not sure, I thought integrate but I'm not entirely sure what I'd be integrating over, it's very hard to go back, I could say "then the tangent plane is flat" but then I'd have to prove if the tangent plane is flat that it's a critical point, I'm not certain of this (I know critical point => tangent plane is flat and I can't think of a counter example going the other way, in-fact the tangent plane is defined by the first derivatives, so perhaps this is the proof? It's fairly easy to show)

**Addendum**

No wonder I'm so muddled, no one looks at $f(x,y)=x+y$ as the sum of two functions, it's like the obvious limit ($\lim_{x\rightarrow a}(x)=a$) only I could prove that, is it not "true because of the definition we use?" and again, what are the both ways, the "if then" and "only then" parts?

Comment: A small note: it might not be a "turning point" in the sense that a derivative of zero does not guarantee a turning point in one dimension, as with $x^3$. But it does mean the graph has one of a handful of qualitative behaviors at the point.

Answer (score 0):

A critical point $(x_0,y_0)$ of a function defined everyone on $\Bbb{R}^2$ is a point where $\nabla f=0$, i.e. $h_x(x_0,y_0)=h_y(x_0,y_0)=0$ (using subscripts for partial derivatives).  Computing the partials, we have

$$
h_x=f_x\\
h_y=g_y
$$ so $h_x(x_0,y_0)=0$ iff $f^\prime(x_0)=0$ and $h_y(x_0,y_0)=0$ iff $g^\prime(y_0)=0$, in other words, $\nabla h=0$ iff $x_0$ is a critical point of $f$ and $y_0$ is a critical point of $g$.